# Linux, PAM_MOUNT, создание целевой директории path

Tags: linux, администрирование, mount

Дано: Ubuntu 16.04 c авторизацией пользователей в AD (samba, winbind, krb, pam-mount).

Пользователь авторизуется и монтируется его домашний каталог если он существует на сервере, а если нет - создается локальный профиль.
/etc/security/pam_mount.conf.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE pam_mount SYSTEM "pam_mount.conf.xml.dtd">
<pam_mount>
<debug enable="2"/>
<volume
    fstype="cifs"
    server="domain.local"
    path="user_home/%(USER)/"
    mountpoint="/home/DOMAIN/%(USER)/"
    options="user=%(USER),noexec"
    user="*"
    pgrp="domain users"
  />
    <mkmountpoint enable="1" remove="true" />
    <logout wait="0" hup="0" term="0" kill="0" />
    <luserconf name=".pam_mount.conf.xml" />
    <mntoptions allow="user,nosuid,nodev,loop,nonempty,noexec" />
</pam_mount>
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, с помощью какого механизма можно создать директорию (от имени пользователя - права есть) на СЕТЕВОМ РЕСУРСЕ в случае ее отсутствия.

Comment: механизм называется *useradd* (это программа такая). нужно вызвать её (с соответствующими аргументами) при [создании нового пользователя](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Adding_users_with_samba_tool).

Comment: ни к *pam*, ни к *mount* вопрос вообще не имеет ни малейшего отношения.

Answer (score 0):

Надо монтировать не home на сетевом ресурсе, а родительскую директорию (хранилище профилей). А точкой монтирования делать /home/DOMAIN/.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE pam_mount SYSTEM "pam_mount.conf.xml.dtd">
<pam_mount>
<debug enable="2"/>
<volume
    fstype="cifs"
    server="domain.local"
    path="user_home/"
    mountpoint="/home/DOMAIN/"
    options="user=%(USER),noexec"
    user="*"
    pgrp="domain users"
  />
    <mkmountpoint enable="1" remove="true" />
    <logout wait="0" hup="0" term="0" kill="0" />
    <luserconf name=".pam_mount.conf.xml" />
    <mntoptions allow="user,nosuid,nodev,loop,nonempty,noexec" />
</pam_mount>
```

Тогда pam_mkhomedir.so, который мы прописали в /etc/pam.d/common-session

```
session optional pam_mkhomedir.so skel=/etc/skel/ umask=0077
```

Сам создаст профиль пользователя.